# Proof related to Ward's Method

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, data, hierarchical-data-format

According to Ward's Method that says :

[image]

Comment: Consider a random element of $A \union B$ for example and it's distance from the mean. Assuming that A,B,C represent axes on 3D, the this random element distance is a diagonal, thus longer than distance on each axis. This is a hint.

Comment: Could you simplify it by graph?